# Spark SQL Streaming with Kafka and Cassandra integration. Force Cassandra to read on need basis

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

Below is a simple program , which has Spark streaming with Kafka , and I have a lookup table in Cassandra for which I have created dataset.

The below sample program reads Kafka-message, and finds the last digit of offset in the message, and then does a lookup for that value for that in Cassandra.

I was able to successfully make it work, but I'm not able to analyze the performance.

In my case, I have 50 million users in a Cassandra table , and I cannot simple create a dataset and keep it in memory like the sample below. So I'm hoping that Cassandra can do a fast lookup (seek) per record on need basis, and our cluster support 20,000 reads per minute.

How can I tell the below Spark program to lookup each value on need, and not load the entire Cassandra data in memory.

Any advise is appreciated.

Java Program

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0)
            throw new Exception("Usage program configFilename");
        String configFilename = args[0];
        ConfigLoader.loadConfig(configFilename);
        sparkSession = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName(SparkKafkaCassandraIntegration.class.getName())
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
                .master(ConfigLoader.getValue("master")).getOrCreate();
        SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
        context.setLogLevel(ConfigLoader.getValue("logLevel"));

        SQLContext sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext();
        System.out.println("Spark context established");

        HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
        tempMap.put("table", "sample_lookup");
        tempMap.put("keyspace", "lookups");
        Dataset<Row> dataset1 = sparkSession.read()
                .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(tempMap).load();
        dataset1.createOrReplaceTempView("cassandraView");

        sqlCtx.sql("select * from cassandraView").show(false);
        DataStreamReader kafkaDataStreamReader = sparkSession.readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", ConfigLoader.getValue("brokers"))
                .option("group.id", ConfigLoader.getValue("groupId"))
                .option("subscribe", ConfigLoader.getValue("topics"))
                .option("failOnDataLoss", false);

        Dataset<Row> rawDataSet = kafkaDataStreamReader.load();
        rawDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("sourceView");

        String kafka_join_cassandra_stream = "select topic, partition, offset, lookup_value from " +
                " sourceView sv join cassandraView cv on cast(sv.offset%10 as string) = lookup_id ";

        sqlCtx.sql(kafka_join_cassandra_stream)
                .writeStream()
                .format("console")
                .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                .trigger(ProcessingTime.create(
                        Integer.parseInt(ConfigLoader.getValue("kafkaProcessingTimeInSeconds"))
                        , TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .start()
                .awaitTermination();
    }
```

Cassandra Table

```
CREATE KEYSPACE lookups WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };
USE lookups;
CREATE table sample_lookup (
    lookup_id  TEXT, 
    lookup_value  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (lookup_id));
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '0', 'Zero');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '1', 'One');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '2', 'Two');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '3', 'Three');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '4', 'Four');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '5', 'Five');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '6', 'Six');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '7', 'Seven');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '8', 'Eight');
INSERT INTO sample_lookup (lookup_id, lookup_value ) VALUES ( '9', 'Nine');
```

POM File

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Sample output

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+------------------+---------+------+------------+
|             topic|partition|offset|lookup_value|
+------------------+---------+------+------------+
|sample-topic      |        0|251826|         Six|
+------------------+---------+------+------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+------------------+---------+------+------------+
|             topic|partition|offset|lookup_value|
+------------------+---------+------+------------+
|sample-topic      |        0|251827|       Seven|
+------------------+---------+------+------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 3
-------------------------------------------
+------------------+---------+------+------------+
|             topic|partition|offset|lookup_value|
+------------------+---------+------+------------+
|sample-topic      |        0|251828|       Eight|
+------------------+---------+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using join you will not be able to push down filters to Cassandra. That is possible only if you specify `where lookup_id=?`.

I would suggest to look into [`stream.foreach(writer)` approach](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamWriter.scala#L331). It will benefit to process each record one by one and query Cassandra with `where lookup_id=?`, which should be pushed down to Cassandra.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Writing I don't have problem at all. In the above case I'm reading the data from Cassandra as lookup. Based on the each record from Kafka I want to do an appropriate lookup in Cassandra and then emit the data to other kafka topic

Comment: As alternative way, `mapPartitions` will probably be even easier way.

Comment: Agreed. Even my Kafka is a micro-batch of 5 minutes. I need to do the custom partition and then do a join Cassandra table. I don't think there is a easy and efficient way to do in Spark-SQL just by writing queries. Any advise on creating custom partition ?